# Problems with getMgmtDisc (from edgar): "no filing information found" or "object ´words.count´ not found"

Tags: r, edgar

I am unfortunately working with R for the first time and I am having a problem with the package "edgar".

My code is as follows:
Normal:

```
MgmtDisc <- getMgmtDisc(cik.no = c(1390777, 1077771, 70858, 1409775, 821127,
                        1049782),
                        filing.year = c(2016, 2017, 2018))
```

or

With a loop:

```
cik_vector <- c(1390777, 1077771, 70858, 1409775, 821127, 1049782)
years <- c(2016, 2017, 2018)

for (i in seq_along(cik_vector)) {
  for (j in seq_along(years)) {
  print(i)
  MgmtDisc <- getMgmtDisc(cik.no = cik_vector[i],
                        filing.year = years[i])
}}
```

I am trying to pull the 10-K filings from the SEC via the edgar package. More specifically, I would like to get the Management Discussion and the Business Describtion. So on the one hand I use the formula getMgmtDisc and getBusinDescr. However, for both of them I have two problems.

1. sometimes the code works and I get the full filings, but sometimes I don't get anything at all, even though I haven't changed anything in the code and just restarted R or similar.

In this case I get the following error message:

```
No filing information found for given CIK(s) and Form Type in the mentioned year(s)/quarter(s).
No annual statements found for given CIK(s) and year(s).
```

Although I know this is not true.

2. if the code for the filings worked then, but sometimes/most of the time I still don't get the management discussion or the business description. Sometimes only for certain years, even though I know they exist for all years. It just changes very randomly.

In this case, the following error message appears:

```
Error in getMgmtDisc(cik.no = cik_vector[i], filing.year = years[i]) : 
  object 'words.count' not found
```

I have tried it with a normal code as well as with a loop. (By the way, is the loop correct?).

Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: You give the impression of asking about more than one problem, "I am having a lot of difficulties.". Better try to be perceived as focusing on only one problem. And instead of abusing non-answering posts elsewhere to advertise your 1h old question here, please study  https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers and while you are at it, please also take the [tour] which probably was highly recommended to you when starting your participation in this community. And [ask].

Comment: I am sorry, this is my first time here. You are right and I will do it as you recommended. Nevertheless, do you know maybe a solution for me?

Comment: No idea about R and edgar. Nice that you took the tour. The other links will help you improving your question. Any [edit], but especially any change to the better, will attract new users to look at this. (But do not attempt to "bump" with irrelevant changes, that would get you again the wrong kind of attention....) But anyway, you take hints and critic and react cooperatively. So here is what I should have written earlier: Sincerely welcome to StackOverflow.